# How to connect to Microsoft cloud services using ExpressRoute from home network?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, nfs, nat, azure-virtual-network

I am prototyping mounting a azure blob storge account as NFS drive, part of it i have configured as it specified in the following docs, however i don't have success with site to point vpn solution

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support-how-to?tabs=windows
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support

i would like to try "An on-premises network that is connected to your primary VNet by using VPN Gateway or an ExpressRoute gateway"

to try this do i need additional configuration on my home router? my ISP assigned with a static IP. What additional networking configurations are needed so that i can connect azure blob storage over NFS via express route?

Answer (score 1):

From [supported network connections for NFS3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support#supported-network-connections), it should work by using a VPN gateway or an ExpressRoute gateway from an on-premise network.

If you are using point to site VPN connection, you could reference from [tunneling traffic over a virtual private network or ExpressRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-overview#tunneling-traffic-over-a-virtual-private-network-or-expressroute) to configure a private endpoint and enable a service endpoint for your storage account in that VPN VNet, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-configure-p2s-vpn-windows#deploy-a-virtual-network). When you use When you create a private endpoint, ensure that your client could resolve the Azure storage account FQDN to a private IP address, for this, you need to [configure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-overview#private-endpoints-and-dns) on your environment.